# Playback recorded microphone audio from SpeechRecognition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, pyaudio

While [*SpeechRecognition*](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) makes it incredible easy to do speech-to-text transcription, I am puzzled how to playback the recorded audio (type `speech_recognition.AudioData`). I did quite some googleing and tried some libraries almost at random (e.g. [*playsound*](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/), [*pydub*](https://pypi.org/project/pydub/)) but didn't made it work. I guess it's no problem when first writing the audio in memory to a file and than playing it back but I am quite stunned that no one ever wanted to play this back immediately from memory (perhaps I am overrating my googleing-skills^^).

Clearly the recognizer instance doesn't require this feature but wouldn't it be nice to check if one must adjust the ambient noise?

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

# Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)
rec = sr.Recognizer()

# Reading Microphone as source
# listening the speech and store in audio_text variable
with sr.Microphone() as source: #device_index=1
    print("Talk")
    audio_text = rec.listen(source)
    print("thx")

# TODO: play back 'audio_text'
```